# use of count() in jupyter notebook. I do not understand why I either get no output, or the wrong output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am in a jupyter notebook in colab:

**First chunk returns nothing. No error.  Just nothing:**

```
   vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']
    
    # count element 'i'
    count = vowels.count('i')
```

**Second chunk returns 0**

```
 names = ['anne', 'chris', 'daniel', 'denise', 'jacob', 'lisa', 'maria']

 names.count('i')
```

Comment: Did you actually print the value of `count`? Your second chunk should return `0`, there are no `i` values in `names`.

Comment: print(names) returns <br/> ['anne', 'chris', 'daniel', 'denise', 'jacob', 'lisa', 'maria']  <br/> mynames= names.count('i') <br/> print(mynames) returns 0

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter notebook, the second codeblock outputs zero because the value of `names.count('i')` is not stored into a variable, so it is printed. The first codeblock doesn't return anything, because the value of `names.count('i')` is stored in the count variable. If you want to see the value, you have to use `print(count)`.

Comment: print(names) returns ['anne', 'chris', 'daniel', 'denise', 'jacob', 'lisa', 'maria']     mynames= names.count('i') print(mynames) returns 0

Comment: @RobertCline This is correct behavior. `print(names)` should print the list `names`, which it does. `print(mynames)` should return zero because none of the strings in the list `names` is 'i', so that is also working correctly.

Comment: I see.   print(names.count('chris'))       Returns 1  which is correct.   How do you ask python to count a specific letter within a name?

Answer (score 0):

Once I understood what DapperDuck was trying to tell me, I tried

```
 myname= names.count('chris')
print(myname)
```

The result was one.  I don't know if you can use count to count the 'i', but I figured out that the way to count the number of times 'i' appears in names is:

```
sum('i' in s for s in names)
```